# Run Visual Studio in memory?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, in-memory

Is it possible to run Visual Studio entirely in memory, and does anyone know how?

I heard that this was possible, and that it makes Visual Studio run a lot quicker than when it is run from disk. I've searched around and can't find anything on it, but getting sick of my intellisense freezing up on me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a ram disk, such as AMD RamDisk. And install it or copy it to there. It should have an option to backup the ramdisk on shutdown.

[AMD Ramdisk][1]
http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/radeon-memory/Pages/ramdisk-overview.aspx

Alternatively, buy an SSD which will have a great performance increase over your HDD, and doesn't have the downsides of running stuff from ram (ie losing data on power loss, having to backup to hdd at shutdown etc).

Comment: thanks Davos, will give this a try. I swear there was an old S.Hanselman article that told you how to do similar using built in windows software? Can't find the article though

Comment: I think you used to be able to do it with ramdisk.sys in windows/dos. Was a lot older version though! I think using something like the AMD ramdisk system is the way to go as is manages saves to disk etc.